# unbound controls table using ADO.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ado.net, databound-controls

how to fill table/grid through unbound control using ADO.NET C#.

```
    using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection())
    {
        Connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
        Connection.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Query + ItemIndex, Connection);
        DataSet DataSet = new DataSet();

        Adapter.Fill(DataSet);
        unbndgrdRecord.DataSource = DataSet;
        unbndgrdRecord.DataBind();
    }
```

this is the code i want to convert this in unbound control...

Comment: Need some more information.  If `unbndgrdRecord` is a GridView, this code should work.  If not, what type of control is `unbndgrdRecord`?

Comment: this code works perfectly but lately I come to know this is databound control code not unbound control an unbound control is that which doesn't have a data source.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.  Any control meant to display data (GridView, Repeater, DetailsView, etc) is worthless until it is bound to a data source.  In your code above you are filling what I assume is a GridView with data.  Until you call `DataBind();` the GridView is unbound.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i am trying that on clicking the search button, the program should query/search all child records that are related to the selected parent record and return details in the table/grid (or any other control that shows tabular data) using unbounded control the given code is of bound control which is of no use.

Comment: Now I understand.  Your problem is very common and you should be able to find a lot of tutorials.  The `GridView` and `DetailsView` were designed with this case in mind.  Here's a tutorial I found on MSDN you can use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581796.aspx